# About encoded proplems between python and C++

Tags: python, c++, encoding, utf-8, gbk

I use python3.8 and C++, G++ for C++.
If I write Chinese(in Unicode) string in C++ program, It will show me wrong string when I run the program,like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "你好" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But, run it:

```
D:\Desktop>g++ test.cpp -o test

D:\Desktop>test.exe
浣犲ソ
```

Although maybe you don't understand Chinese, you can see that it's not string I want.

If I change the encoded to "gbk",this problem was solved,but another proplem come out when I run python:

```
print("你好")
```

result:

```
File "test.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xc4' in file test.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

By the way,this is a part of my vimrc(Gvim's config) about encoded:

```
set fileencodings=utf-8,gbk,ucs-bom,utf-16,utf-32,gbk,big5,gb18030,latin1,gb2312
set encoding=gbk
set termencoding=gb2312
set fileencoding=gbk
" This will make Python be errored
```

```
set fileencodings=utf-8,gbk,ucs-bom,utf-16,utf-32,gbk,big5,gb18030,latin1,gb2312
set encoding=utf-8
set termencoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
" This will make C++ string wrong
```

How can I find a encoded that C++ and Python string can both right?
I use Gvim to edit my C++ and Python code in Windows, thank you for your help!

Comment: Does Python work ok with gbk if you add `# -*- coding: gbk -*-` at the top of your python source file?

Comment: Thanks! This way is able. But I want to find a simpler way, because my friends don't use gbk encoding maybe, if I share the files with "# -*- coding: gbk -*-",it may make some errors

Comment: If I understand correctly (and I'm not a C++ programmer, so I could be wrong), C++ strings are just encoded bytes, so `你好` in UTF-8 is `\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd`.  So what I think is happening is that C++ sends these bytes to the terminal, but the terminal assumes the bytes are gbk, which happens to use _the same bytes_ for `浣犲ソ`.  So perhaps if you change your terminal's default encoding to UTF-8 then the UTF-8 settings will work for C++ and Python?